# How can I make title dynamically?

Tags: struts2, el, tiles2

I'm developing BBS in struts2 and tiles(2) framework.

I want to push a value in ActionSupport class and pop the value in layout.jsp of tiles. but i just keep failing to access to the value.

I will explain my works step by step.

1) Users click a link to view an article at list page. And BoardView class will be called as defined in struts.xml

--list.jsp--
`<a href="view_board?num=${num}"> ${ subject } </a>`

--struts.xml--
`<action name="View_board" class="board.BoardView">

    <result type="tiles">board.view</result>

</action>`

2)Action class will put title into the value stack... right?

--BoardView class--

```
 
public class BoardView extends ActionSupport

    private String title;

    public void Execute() throws Exception {
        ...  
        setTitle(board.getSubject());
        return SUCCESS; 
    }
    ...  
    (setter and getter of title)
```

3) As ActionClass returns SUCCESS, it will go to tiles definition named  board.view
--struts.xml--
`<action name="View_board" class="board.BoardView">

    <result type="tiles">board.view</result>

</action>`

4)Here's the tiles-def.xml and the problem. I think the value of 'title' can't be popped from value stack.
==tiles-def.xml==
`<definition name="board.view" extends="layout">

  <put-attribute name="title" value="%title" />

  <put-attribute name="body" value="/board/view.jsp" />

</definition>`
(I can't indent with tags... sorry)
Here's the layout.jsp
==layout.jsp==
`...
<title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title>
...`

I tried to replace the value attribute to %{title}, $title and ${title}. But nothings worked out. Web Browser just shows the string itself($title).

I don't know what to do... please help me.

I hope you all understand my works despite my bad explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As my solution on current Project.

1. In template jsp: put `<c:out value="${pageTitle}" default="My Title"></c:out>`
2. So, in every actions class, you should create the variable pageTitle to DYNAMIC Title.

Comment: @Marko - if you're going to upvote every single late answer you come across, please at least improve the ones that need them.  This answer needed formatting to properly show the code; as it was, the answer you approved made no sense.